# Gitlab CI Pipeline shows RUNNING state when the parent job of a child trigger job is set to manual

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a parent pipeline A that triggers another child pipeline B from another project.  The child pipeline B has a manual action job.  The entire pipeline status shows `RUNNING` when both pipelines has already completed except child pipeline B that still has the manual action to be executed later.  I was expecting the parent status to show `BLOCKED` or `PENDING` when waiting for a manual action.

I'm running Gitlab EE Premium Self-Hosted version `14.10.3-ee`

### Parent Pipeline A

```
parent:pipeline:
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'childproject'
        file: 'pipeline-B.yml'
    strategy: depend
  allow_failure: false
```

### Child Pipeline B

```
deploy:test:
  stage: deploy:staging
  script:
    - env
  rules:
     - when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the  allow_failure: false from the manual job

Comment: Tried that before, with or without is still the same.  Default is always false. There is already a couple of open issue in gitlab regarding this behaviour https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/361574

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).